# Как убрать рамку у изображения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label, photoimage

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно убрать рамку?

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('img/-GlkRC8TPVo.jpg'))
b = Label(self, image=img)
b.grid()
```

Comment: С помощью Photoshop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**boy3.jpg** **`-->`** [**Загрузить изображение и удалите фон**](https://www.remove.bg/upload) **`-->`** **boy33.png**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root = Tk()

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("boy3.jpg"))
imagei = Label(image=image)
imagei.grid(row=1,column=1)

image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("boy33.png"))            # <---- boy33.png
imagei2 = Label(image=image2)
imagei2.grid(row=2,column=1)

button = Button(root, text="click")
button.grid(row=3,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**boy3.jpg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]